# Search engine for ubuntu users

Tags: search, engine

Is there a good search engine to find solutions to the problems that ubuntu users face? Ask Ubuntu has a lot of answers, but there are other places that have relevant information as well. Google doesn't seem to get to the answers very well or often enough.

Is there an internet search engine tailored to the parts of the web that are the linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is of course the amazing [Ask Oli](http://askoli.quickmediasolutions.com/) search engine. Probably one of the best. Actually asking [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) usually has good results too.

There are also many good ubuntu books. I like [Ubuntu Linux Secrets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470395087).

Seriously now, for your purposes http://www.googlubuntu.com/ is probably the way to go.

Comment: Very nice! I already got it bookmarked. I was going to make a joke calling the unknown engine "ubugle" but googlubuntu is better. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free upvote and if that is the case, mark as answered.